# move-construction using C++ constructor arguments

Tags: c++

I always thought that C++ compilers will use a move-constructor in situations like below:

```
#include <string>

struct A {
    std::string str;
    explicit A(std::string s) : str(s) {}  // Isn't |s| moved into |str|?
};

std::string foo(int x) {
    return std::to_string(x);
}

int main() {
    A a(foo(10));
    return a.str.size();
}
```

But apparently (according to Godbolt) not. The generated code (using `-O9`) is much smaller when I change the constructor to `explicit A(std::string s) : str(std::move(s)) {}`, which is surprising. I thought the two would be equivalent. I mean, `s` is basically a temporary, going away, so why doesn't its value get moved into `str`? I even vaguely recall this being a thing ...

Comment: There are no "last-use" thing in C++ for automatic move... (more approaching is automatic-move with return` though).

Comment: `s` isn't a temporary, it has a name.

Comment: You can also use `s` in the constructor body, or in other member initializers. Moving it automatically would make those uses invalid.

Comment: As I understand it, `foo(10)` is moved into `s` indeed, but from `s` into intialization of field `str` you copy construct, because `s` is an lvalue, not rvalue reference. So to move into `str` you need to write the move explicitly

Comment: I believe I got this case confused with 'automatic-move with return' as the first note mentions. Yeah, it's interesting that we have that optimization but no 'automatic-move with last-use'. There must be a reason for that.

Comment: @LajosNagy: We’ve [just been discussing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76367635/implicit-moving-in-return-statement-requiring-a-conversion-operation#comment134664490_76367635).  Do you want to edit this question to explicitly ask why the language doesn’t perform this auto-move on last use (rather than saying “basically a temporary”)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could even make the example more explicit:

```
explicit A(std::string&& s) : str(s) {}
```

This constructor only accepts string rvalues, but `str(s)` still uses the copy constructor. The nuance is that `s` may be initialised with a temporary object in both cases, but the expression `s` is always an lvalue.

Although named return values are also lvalues, in that case it is actually certain that they will go out of scope immediately afterwards. Returned lvalues and other [move-eligible expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#Move-eligible_expressions) are therefore classified as xvalues since C++23. This may seem like a much simpler case, yet [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66712414/1719926) provides a few examples where it was not.

In general, compilers may not alter the observable effects of your program under the "as-if rule", so optimisations exempt from this have to be explicitly specified in the standard. The reason we do not have the feature you describe is probably that it has not been proposed, or was considered too difficulty to specify properly.